# .every function in typescript + angular 2

Tags: javascript, typescript, angular

I am using every function to check if a particular checkbox in the grid is checked or not, I am using angular 2 and below is my code to do that:

```
// Typescript code
this.toggle = this.contactlist.every(item => item.checked);

// JS output is
this.toggle = this.contactlist.every(function(item) {
   return item.checked;
});
```

Now I want to include more code inside that every function so I tried this:

```
this.toggle = this.contactlist.every(item => {
    item.checked; 
    console.log('Item:', item)
});

// In Webpack it gives me this error
Argument of type '(item: any) => void' is not assignable to parameter of type '(value: any, index: number, array: any[]) => boolean'.
  Type 'void' is not assignable to type 'boolean'.
```

How I can solve it?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

change it to

```
this.toggle = this.contactlist.every(item => {
    console.log('Item:', item)
    return item.checked; 
});
```

add `return` part

Comment: One could add why lambdas behave this way.